# How do I refresh one object on a sheet whilst the rest is frozen on Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, graph, refresh

I am fairly new to VBA. I have created a resource that copies from a single cell and creates a string of n number of results. At the same time it creates a graph to the right of the results. When the results go below the view of the page, the sheet jumps back and forth and the graph follows. Is there a way using VBA to keep the entire sheet still (not visibly refreshing) whilst having the graph refresh for each result? Anyone's help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you post the code. There shouldn't really be any need for the sheet to be moving.

Comment: Hello, thanks for getting in touch.
This is the code:
For a = 1 To Range("n").Value
'Copying Crossed to Results
    Range("D18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(a + 16, 2).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
' Creates Needle Drop Graph
'Delete Old Chart
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("PinDrop").Select
    Selection.Delete
'Create Chart
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
    ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "PinDrop"

Comment: The problem is that it keeps going back to copy the result cell (D18) and then jumping down to the last result. This causes the screen the judder and the graph to move down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to select anything there:

```
For a = 1 To Range("n").Value
 'Copying Crossed to Results
 Range("D18").Copy
 Cells(a + 16, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 
' Creates Needle Drop Graph 
'Delete Old Chart 
On Error Resume Next
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("PinDrop").Delete
On Error Goto 0
 'Create Chart 
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
   .ChartType = xlXYScatter 
   .Parent.Name = "PinDrop"
end with
```